# Prevent the Popup in Chrome While Printing using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Javascript**

```
function printPage(htmlPage)
{
   var w = window.open("about:blank");
   w.document.write(htmlPage);
   w.print();
}
```

Here we are opening the window w and then, using the print dialog to print the page. As you know, the Chrome Browser's default print dialog already has a print preview on right side. So, I don't want to show the window w. Is it possible to directly show the Chrome's Print dialog without opening a popup?

Comment: Just some ideas; 1. Use a print stylesheet. 2. Print using a iframe

Comment: how to print using  Print using a iframe.

Comment: First, why do you print a specific html snippet? Can you use a print stylesheet instead?

Comment: Your question is you don't want to show print preview on right side right?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit: I want to show but I don't want to show the popup, which is opening from window.open().

Comment: than where exactly the preview will be shown if you don't want to show the popup?

Answer (score 1):

as hank suggested, you can print from a iframe (can be a hidden one too).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print in iframe</title>
</head>

<body>

<iframe name="PrintFrame" id="PrintFrame" style="display: none"></iframe>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function printPage(htmlPage)
    {
        window.frames["PrintFrame"].document.write(htmlPage);
        window.frames["PrintFrame"].print();

    }
    printPage('<html><head><title></title></head><body><table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table></body></html>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is printing an empty page in chrome, safari and Opera.